# In asp.net mvc what is the use of context.User.Identity.Name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio

I'm currently studying asp.net mvc and I just started, I decided to move away from web forms to mvc.

I'm following this tutorial from codeplex the mvc music store and there's this line of code that I don't understand how it's use and why it's use.

Here is the line of the code:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.User.Identity.Name))
                {
                    context.Session[CartSessionKey] = context.User.Identity.Name;

                }
```

I would like to know what context.User.Identity.Name does because I tried removing the if block it's contained and the app still works.

Here's the full code of that function:

```
 public string GetCartId(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            if (context.Session[CartSessionKey] == null)
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.User.Identity.Name))
                {
                    context.Session[CartSessionKey] = context.User.Identity.Name;

                }
                else
                {
                    // Generate a new random GUID using System.Guid class
                    Guid tempCartId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    // Send tempCartId back to client as a cookie
                    context.Session[CartSessionKey] = tempCartId.ToString();
                }
            }
            return context.Session[CartSessionKey].ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does exactly the same thing it does in Web Forms when you require authentication. Once a user is successfully authenticated `context.User.Identity.Name` contains the username of the person that logged in.

In your particular example, it's simply checking that the user is authenticated -although you should check `Request.IsAuthenticated` instead of checking whether the Username is not null or blank- and putting the Username of the person in `Session[CartSessionKey]`

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the following link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

Implement security in an application and learn Membership provider, it will allow you to understand roles and other things that are very useful for keeping an application secure.